Why does Flutter web load fonts from google?
Why does flutter load 3rd party fonts? Inspecting my app in Chrome...

^^ the last two are loaded from Google.
Even after I specify only one font:
flutter:
  fonts:
     # https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji
     - family: NotoColorEmoji
       fonts:
         - asset: assets/fonts/Noto/NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf

and the application is simply
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(content());
}

Widget content() {
  return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'NotoColorEmoji view',
      // Set NotoColorEmoji as the default app font.
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'NotoColorEmoji'),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Text("☝️⭐"), //const MyHomePage(),
      ));
}


The app then complains:
Could not find a set of Noto fonts to display all missing characters. Please add a font asset for the missing characters. See: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

What gives?

I believe you can find the answer here.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/136118
As of now, there is no built-in way to prevent flutter web app from loading default fonts.
This may not be related but what is usually done for most websites is that fonts would be loaded from google, and this behavior is not necessarily bad as it is the same as loading your font file from your hosting server for example. Anyways ...
Here's what you can do:
Download the Roboto font files and declare them in your pubspec.yaml file and flutter will detect that Roboto is downloaded and will not redownload it from google.
OR
You can rename your font files to Roboto and trick flutter that Roboto(your renamed fonts) is donwloaded and flutter will act as I mentioned before.
This is not guaranteed and some users reported it not working!

It doesn't work for me. (Font still downloaded - at least, if I have a "Roboto" font family registered.).
